# error while committing the transaction error in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, postgresql, transactions, save, commit

HibernateSpatialJPA class:

```
 public class HibernateSpatialJPA {

    private static final EntityManagerFactory emFactory;
    static {
        try {
            emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.hibernate.events.jpa");
        }catch(Throwable ex){
            System.err.println("Cannot create EntityManagerFactory.");
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    public static EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return emFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public static void close(){
        emFactory.close();
    }
}
```

this is manager class:

```
 public class SavegeojsonManager {

    SavegeojsonEntity theEvent = new SavegeojsonEntity();

    public boolean insert(JSONObject json)
    {
        GeoJSON item = new GeoJSON(json);
        return insert(item);
    }

    public boolean insert(GeoJSON item)
    {
        boolean success=false;
        try {

            String vectorType = item.getType();
            EntityManager em = HibernateSpatialJPA.createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            theEvent.setVectorType(vectorType);
            em.persist(theEvent);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
            success=true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            success = false;

        }
        HibernateSpatialJPA.close();
        return success;
    }
}
```

and this is GeoJsonClass :

```
   public class GeoJSON
{

    private int id;

    private String type;
    private String data;

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) {  this.id = id; }

    public String getType() {return type;}
    public void setType(String type) {this.type = type;}

    public String getData() {return data;}
    public void setData(String data) { this.data = data; }

    public GeoJSON() {
    }

    public GeoJSON(JSONObject json) {
        parse(json);
    }


    public GeoJSON parse(JSONObject json) {
        StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
        json.write(out);
        this.data = out.toString();
        this.type = json.getString("type");

        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        return this;
    }

}
```

But I am not able to save into database because error :

enter code here : "error while committing the transaction."

Do you have any idea about this error ?

Below is the Exception stack trace:-

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:92)
at com.springapp.model.SavegeojsonManager.insert(SavegeojsonManager.java:32)
at com.springapp.model.SavegeojsonManager.insert(SavegeojsonManager.java:19)
at com.springapp.mvc.HSpatialController.saveGeoJson(HSpatialController.java:46)
...
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ERROR: column "vectortype" of relation "savegeojson" does not exist Position: 76 at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377) at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300) at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:80) ... 40 more Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ERROR: column "vectortype" of relation "savegeojson" does not exist Position: 76 at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122) at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56) at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2962) at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3403) at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88) at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362) at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354) at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:275) at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1214) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:403) at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101) at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175) at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75) ... 40 more Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "vectortype" of relation "savegeojson" does not exist Position: 76 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2062) at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1795) at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257) at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:479) at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:367) at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:321) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122) ... 56 more
```

Comment: Could you provide full exception stack ?

Comment: {"coordinates":[37.713867723942,39.647461473942],"type":"Point"}
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        springhibernate.public.savegeojson
        (geom, geom1, geom2, geom3, vectorType, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Error while committing the transaction  @PawełGłowacz

Comment: Please do this in your code and paste all your stack trace into the question `catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }`

Comment: I could not do as comments. I have added in response . Sorry. @PawełGłowacz

Comment: @SevgiÇakmak, i am putting your exception stack trace in question section.

Comment: Thank you very much @AshishPatil                                                             Do you have any solution please?

Comment: @SevgiÇakmak, exception itself says, `ERROR: column "vectortype" of relation "savegeojson" does not exist`.. check in your table configuration for column if it is exist or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving Entity `SavegeojsonEntity` to postgresql db and this error means:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "vectortype" of relation "savegeojson" does not exist
      Position: 76
```

Table that `SavegeojsonEntity` are mapped to does not have column `vectortype`. Check in your db that column exists in table.
If it does not exist you need to add that column to table.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going back to work to correct the error.I'll get back to you. Pawel ve Ashish thank you very much.

Comment: Mark as answered if this was satisfied. Cheers.